# Load and Run WPF DLL into Another WPF exe

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

My main issue is as I stated in title.

WPF_APP1 --> I created dll of this wpf project after excluding App.xaml
WPF_APP2  --> Normal WPF exe. which needs to run the above WPF_APP1 dll and open the WPF_APP1 MainWindow form using reflection.

Why I am saying  for reflection is - 
**WPF_APP2** first get the latest **WPF_APP1.dll** then open so can not add the reference of dll. have to use the Reflection only.

When I use the above dll in cmd project its okay. it open the CMD window then launch the **WPF_APP1 MainWindow** as Window form.

But Now I need to open this window form not in cmd, in **WPF_APP2**.

Please help me out.

CMD project use the below code to open the **WPF_APP1** MainWindow.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();                   
    }


    private static void ThreadProc()
    {
        string loc = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName
                      + "\\AutoUpdateTesting.dll";

        Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(loc);

        foreach (Type type in dll.GetExportedTypes())
        {                
            if (type.Name.Equals("MainWindow"))
            {                   
                dynamic n = null;
                n = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                n.InitializeComponent();
                System.Windows.Application apprun = new System.Windows.Application();
                apprun.Run(n);

                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

I can not use line  -

```
    System.Windows.Application apprun = new System.Windows.Application();
```

In WPF_APP2 because of AppDomain(found this reason on google).  Try other alternative but no luck.

Please have a look and share your knowledge.  :)

waiting for your comments and reply.

Thanks

Comment: did you also try to load the same in a new app domain?

Comment: Yes I try.. I created new app domain.. but try to load - 

`Could not load file or assembly 'XXXX\\XXXX\\AutoUpdateTesting.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`


.. and when try to execute it says no entry point..

Comment: execution is only possible for an executable. do you want to invoke the main window from dll as a new application or just want to display the window? is it possible for you to post a working sample of the code in the question?

Comment: the above code is working with cmd project.. from wpf_app2 I want to launch the wpf_app1 which is a dll as separate process.. then dispose the wpf_app2(parent wpf app)

Comment: @pushpraj thanks for you continue support and interest.. Stian answered my question below.. ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Load WPF window from forms application:**

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        ThreadProc();
        Application.Run(); // Keep on running!
    }

    private static void ThreadProc()
    {
        if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
            new System.Windows.Application();
        try
        {
            string assemblyName = string.Format("{0}\\AutoUpdateTesting.dll", new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName);
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                Window wnd = LoadAssembly(assemblyName, "OtherWindow");
                wnd.Show();
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message));
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message), ex);
        }
    }

    private static Window LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly assemblyInstance = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
            foreach (Type t in assemblyInstance.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, typeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                var wnd = assemblyInstance.CreateInstance(t.FullName) as Window;
                return wnd;
            }
            throw new Exception("Unable to load external window");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0}{1}", assemblyName, ex.Message));
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load external window{0}", assemblyName), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

That does the trick for forms! Remember that you need to add references to the base WPF assemblies(PresentationCore, WindowBase+++)

**WPF loading external window** (Read your post wrong, so here you have wpf to wpf as well)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    App()
    {
        Startup += App_Startup;
    }

    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string assemblyName = string.Format("{0}\\AutoUpdateTesting.dll", new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName);
            Window wnd = LoadAssembly(assemblyName, "OtherWindow");
            wnd.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message));
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to load window from{0} - {1}", "OtherWindow", ex.Message), ex);

        }
    }

    private Window LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly assemblyInstance = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
            foreach (Type t in assemblyInstance.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, typeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                var wnd = assemblyInstance.CreateInstance(t.FullName) as Window;
                return wnd;
            }
            throw new Exception("Unable to load external window");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to load window from{0}{1}", assemblyName, ex.Message));
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load external window{0}", assemblyName), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Stian

Comment: Thanks man.. !! really appreciate.. :) I would like to ask one thing more.. pls..!  
`it worked as I want.. perfect.. only thing when I open parent form and then it creates the instance of WPF inside dll and show it as window, perfect..!! can you please let me know how to dispose the parent wpf form after starting the wpf from dll`

Comment: @DeepakSharma NP! :) It should just be to call wnd.Close(); Possibly you have to remove references to it, if you store it somewhere(not on the stack scope) you should remove the ref, to make sure that it gets garbage collected. That is given that I understand you correctly, and you just want to shut the window? If you want exit the application you may call [Application.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx) to shut down the forms application

Comment: `wnd.close();` to close the form which was in assembly.. right? But I'm saying to close the parent form not the form which was in assembly.. first (parent) was wpf application.. so I used `App.Current.Shutdown();` but this closed the both form.. parent wpf one and the second which was loaded from assembly.. but I want to close the first wpf only, not the second one which was loaded from assembly.. hope it makes sense..

Comment: @DeepakSharma No this will [close your WPF window.]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close(v=vs.110).aspx). And yes App.Current.Shutdown() will shut the WPF Application down. How this interacts with forms, I have to check out and maybe belongs in another thread. I'll look around later, but right now I gtg. Are you thiking of unloading an entire assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a suggestion:

I would change :

```
foreach (Type type in dll.GetExportedTypes())
{                
    if (type.Name.Equals("MainWindow"))
    {                   
        dynamic n = null;
        n = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        n.InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Application apprun = new System.Windows.Application();
        apprun.Run(n);

        break;
    }
}
```

with:

```
// replacing the loop, brackets and break with:
var main_win = dll.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.Name.Equalts("MaindWindow");

dynamic n = null;
n = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
n.InitializeComponent();
System.Windows.Application apprun = new System.Windows.Application();
apprun.Run(n);
```

Let linq worry about it, and make your code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: hehehe.. good one.. but here I am looking for answer not an reframing the code.. well I am enough good in linq its just to make understable to every one who dont know the linq..

Comment: This is why I've started with : "Not an answer, but a suggestion" :). It also makes your code more readable. Besides, chances are that since this is not trivial stuff, any person who can give you a correct answer, will know enough linq to read a `.Where` clause :)