# Execute some methods from existing WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

There is some wpf based application. I need to implement windows shell SendTo functionality for it. SendTo should execute some operation from my existing application, that is also already available in my app, with files got as SendTo result.

My idea is to write second app, intended to be executed as SendTo result and add main app as reference to it, so I will able to execute only needed part of its code as my SendTo command.

Is it good idea? Or I rather should to avoid approach like this? My main app is not so simple, it uses much wpf stuff and services/automapper to access to database - of course, action to execute as SendTo needs to have opened database connection.

Comment: You rather mean WCF?

Comment: Adding to @Icepickle's comment, it seems like you mean WCF.  Additionally, your question is unclear, are you asking if you can call one app from another app?  Or if you should use the same service for two different apps?  Perhaps a simple diagram would go a long way here.

Comment: No. I need to load some window from existing wpf assembly. Why vote down? This assembly is exe, not dll so it's actually full working wpf app. I need to show some window included in my application as SendTo result. I hope it's clear

Comment: Very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579656/load-and-run-wpf-dll-into-another-wpf-exe

Comment: then what is stopping you from using the method in the very similar question?

Comment: I don't have extracted anything to dll. Also, will I able to load assembly in my exe while exe is running?